# What's a good way to make these columns containing a list on the left side and an image on the right side responsive?

Tags: html, css

I want to make the list on the left column and image on the right column completely responsive in terms of desktop, portrait and landscape mobile.  Below's my attempt and here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4omke6a/6/) as well. I know I probably need to adjust the text size and image size as well but I've tried too many ways but to no avail.

Anyone know a good way to achieve this?

```css
.last-sec {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrappa {
  display: flex;
}

.ltl-list {
  width: 50%;
}

.ltl-img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="lest-sec">
  <div class="wrappa">
    <div class="ltl-list">
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
        <li>Six</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="ltl-img">
      <img src="https://img.fireden.net/co/image/1548/91/1548913348696.png" alt="image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please be more specific. With the vague description: You can change layouts with the sue of media queries. Being responsive his a very broad concept. As such you need to be more specific with a specific layout or description of what should happen.

Comment: @tacoshy I meant like, making it appear side to side right next to each other on desktop and then on mobile it appears top to bottom (list on top, image on bottom)

Comment: how big do you want the proportions in desktop view? currently you overflowing horizontally how much width in % should the list take and how much width the image? should be a gap between those 2 elements? How much of a gap?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s4omke6a/6/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
.last-sec {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrappa {
  display: flex;
}

.ltl-list {
  width: 50%;
}

.ltl-img {
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
  .ltl-list {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .ltl-img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply include `media queries` define they breakpoint at which screen width it should switch from horizotnal to vertical placement.

In my example i have the breakpoint at 480px. At 480px or below it will be placed below each other, at 481px or above horizontally next to each other:

```
/* only applies to smartphones */
@media only screen
  and (max-width: 480px) {
    .wrappa {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
        
    .ltl-list,
    .ltl-img {
      width: 100%;
    }
}

/* appleis to all screens larger then 480px */
@media only screen
  and (min-width: 481px) {
    .wrappa {
      flex-direction: row;
    }
        
    .ltl-list {
      width: 30%;
    }

    .ltl-img {
      width: 70%;
    }
}
```

Next I did some refining so that it is fully responsive. I changed the image CSS to `object-fit: contain;` so it only takes the space availabe and re-sizes to maintain aspect ratio. It does not overflow horizontally anymore.

```css
.last-sec {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrappa {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.ltl-img img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

@media only screen
  and (max-width: 480px) {
    .wrappa {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .ltl-list,
    .ltl-img {
      width: 100%;
    }
}

@media only screen
  and (min-width: 481px) {
    .wrappa {
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    
    .ltl-list {
      width: 30%;
    }

    .ltl-img {
      width: 70%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="lest-sec">
  <div class="wrappa">
    <div class="ltl-list">
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
        <li>Six</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="ltl-img">
      <img src="https://img.fireden.net/co/image/1548/91/1548913348696.png" alt="image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Responsive design can be achieved by using `display: flex` combining with `flex-grow`:

```css
body>div {
  background: #aaa;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

body>div>div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

body>div>div:nth-child(even) {
  background: lightgreen;
}

body>div>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: lightpink;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  body>div>div {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="ltl-list">
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
        <li>Six</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="ltl-img">
      <img src="https://img.fireden.net/co/image/1548/91/1548913348696.png" alt="image">
    </div>
```